# What is my Pinarello model?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought this last year as a just a frame and forks. I built it up to ride but have only done about 100 miles. All I know about it is the frame and forks are steel  I used what stem I had laying around at the time so I know it makes it look a bit ugly. I fitted a Campagnolo Veloce group set and new set of Miche wheels.

I'm looking at getting the proper stem for it as the one I had does not look right obviously. I have spent many hours looking at what the exact model is but to no avail. Could someone help me please?

[image: ent[![enter image description here]

I can list more if needed, there is no serial no on the bottom , only the words pinnarello

Comment: Ask the seller.

Comment: BSE has a fairly abysmal record identifying bikes. This sounds like one that might be possible though. Please add a well lit, clear photo of the whole bike from the drive side, and of any particular features that may help identify it. You need to add those promptly as you are already attracting close votes.  You got an upvote so you have sufficient reputation to add images.

Comment: If it was authentic I would have expected a serial number under the BB, or by the rear dropouts.  There is no Pinarello serial DB on the web, so you have to contact customer support for authentication with your serial number.  If it is a knockoff, then its still a nice looking steel bike to be ridden.

Comment: the chap I bought it off was heavily into his bikes and i would be very surprised if he bought a fake one. On the bottom bracket it just has the words pinarello stamped into the frame. I could not work out why it has no serial no.  I want to sell the bike but only when i find out exactly what its history is. I would not sell it to someone if it was fake.

Comment: I note that your bike has mudguard/fender mounts on the forks and drop-outs, which suggests that it's not an out-and-out racing bike. Did Pinarello ever make such a bike? Pinarello's dropouts also typically have a triangular hole in them (see, e.g., [steel-vintage.com](https://www.steel-vintage.com/bicycles/pinarello/)), which yours lack.

Comment: Can you add a pic of the "Pinarello" stamp on the BB shell?

Answer (score 3):

The frame seems suspicious: it clearly was TIG-welded, just look at those smooth tube joints and compare to 80s lugged frames, which means the MY should be at least in mid 90s. [The Dyna looks very similar](http://rides.smetschka.com/?p=126), but the the dropouts don't match (holes vs no holes). Newer frames either have seatpost bolt inline with top tube or a modern collar, but the frame in question has the bolt at least a centimeter higher than the top of the top tube. The paint doesn't match the time period either, [the most similar paint jobs date to 80s](https://www.lfgss.com/conversations/193267/) lugged frames, just like the head badge. I think it was repainted with the use of an [aftermarket decals set](https://bicycledecals.net/images/Pinarello_SET_9.jpg).

I'd look for any branding cues in every crook and nanny and ask the previous owner about the model and paint job.

Comment: This looks more like a 2000s steel bike than 80s. The tube shapes look a lot like Columbus Spirit from the time.

Comment: Also, a quick Google for images of "Pinarello steel" didn't seem to give any results with "Pinarello" written _four_ times on each side of the bike.  They all seem to have it on the down tube; most, but not all, have it either on each side of the seat tube or down the front of it; a few have it at the front of the top tube, but I didn't see any with "Pinarello" on the chain stay.

Comment: Its a mystery this bike.

Comment: I did write to steel vintage .com on 2 occasions but they never replied.I am starting to get very disappointing results after so much searching on the web. i cannot trace the previous owner for answers. I may see if Columbo is free at the weekend to investigate, i tried Kojak but he is on another case....